# How to get all lines from a file to EOF?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, sh

I hope someone can help me to solve the problem. I found a lot of topics around reading files with sed, but nothing fits to my case. Maybe someone knows the solution to following situation:

I have a logger that creates a file of a defined size (in my case 5MB). The logger uses the file like a ring buffer and writes the logger information into this file. The logger starts at, of course, line 1 and remarks the end with eof. In a hex editor, it looks like this:

```
0d 3c 3c 3c 45 4f 46 3e 3e 3e 0d 20 20 20 20 20  .<<<EOF>>>.
```

Now I have two situations, an easy one and a complex one:

1. I need to print from start to the end identifier.
2. The most beautiful solution recognizes if after EOF are initial values (0x20), then print from line 1 to EOF. If there are values after end of line identifier then read all after EOF until file size and then from line one to EOF identifier. This should print out all lines of this "ring buffer". Is something like this possible?

To solve (1) I tried some `sed` commands, e.g.:

```
sed -e '1,$p' test.log > result.txt
```

-> Aim: print everything from line 1 to EOF patter, but both files have the same size (in my case 5MB). It looks like $p refers to the real end of file and not to the EOF pattern.

```
sed -e '/EOF/,$d' test.log > result.txt
```

-> Aim: print everything before EOF pattern, but result.txt has the size 0.

Can anybody offer any hints or solutions to solve this?

Comment: What does "remarks the end with eof" mean?  How do you write eof to a file? Do you mean the literal string `"EOF"` or something else? Why is there a space in `<<< EOF>>>` in your hex editor output? Halfway through your question you imply the file is initially filled with `0x20` characters, it would be more helpful to say that at the start if that's true.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The file contains `.<<<EOF>>>.` as a marker. Why, don't ask.

Comment: But your hex bytes show `0d 3c 3c 3c 45 4f 46 3e 3e 3e 0d` which has no space, i.e. `.<<<EOF>>>.` not `.<<< EOF>>>.`

Comment: It's also confusing asking about how to get all lines up to EOF, when that's what `cat` does, because EOF means end-of-file. You mean get all lines up to a specific pattern (which just happens to be `"EOF"` in your case, but could be `"AAA"` instead and the solution would be the same)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yes, without space is correct. Sorry!

Comment: I tried cat also, but if I make "cat test.log > result.log" I have two identically file with size of 5MB. But only the first I guess 10kB are really filled up with information.

Comment: Of course, because `cat` reads the whole file.  You seem to be confused that the string `"EOF"` has some magic meaning that `sed` and `cat` recognise. It doesn't. It's just a sequence of three characters, `E`, `O` and `F`.

Comment: But then the command "sed -e '/EOF/,$d' test.log > result.txt" should recognize this three characters and prints out the file from first line to this pattern. But this does not work, so I think I did a mistake here. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: That command works for me.

Comment: looks like proprietary solution. linux software would use logrotate for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, I think you need two commands (and two scans of the file):

```
logfile="…some-name…"
eofmark="<<<EOF>>>"

sed -n "/$eofmark/,\$ { /$eofmark/d; p; }" $logfile  # Read the tail material
sed -n "1,/$eofmark/  { /$eofmark/d; p; }" $logfile  # Read the head material
```

Using `perl` or `awk`, you could slurp the whole file into memory, and then print the tail part followed by the head part.  For example, in `awk`:

```
logfile="…some-name…"
eofmark="<<<EOF>>>"

awk "/$eofmark/"' {eofline = NR}
     {line[NR] = $0}
     END { for (i = eofline+1; i <= NR; i++) print line[i]
           for (i = 1; i < eofline; i++) print line[i]
     }' $logfile
```

This is feasible since reading a 5 MiB file into memory won't stress machines with gigabytes of main memory.  If the file itself was gigabytes of data, you'd think twice about slurping it into memory, though scanning it twice would also be painful.